# What is the best way to in Swift to test if running under OS X or iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I'm writing a framework in Swift that is used in OS X and iOS programs. What is the best way **at runtime** to find out if a method is running under OS X or iOS?

At **compile time** it is easy:

```
#if os(iOS)
    println("iOS")
    #else
    println("OS X")
#endif
```

At **runtime** there is `NSProcessInfo()` and it's methods to gather information like `operatingSystemVersion` and `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:`, but they don't distinguish between the operating system type itself.

`operatingSystem` and `operatingSystemName` would be great, but they marked deprecated and are not available in Swift.

Comment: `#if os(iOS)
    let os = 0
    #else
    let os = 1
#endif`? ;)

Comment: whats wrong with compile time? you must compile separately anyway